# How to load a div with a flash object, but not display it (element loaded, not displayed)

Tags: javascript, html, css, flash, swfobject

I'm looking for something between `display: none` and `visibility: hidden`. In other words, I want for div element (with flash content) to be loaded, but not displayed at all.

To make it more clear: there is a flash object embedded through `swfobject.embedSWF` in the div. When I change `display` (via javascript) from `block` to `none` and then from `none` to `block`, it works different in different browsers:

in IE it works like I want it to work - I change the display to `block` and the object is still there, but in Chrome and FF it is loaded again, like for the first time when `swfobject.embedSWF` was called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about setting it to

HTML (somewhere on the page)

```
<body>
  <!-- other code -->
  <div id="my-div">
    <!-- your object / embed code -->
  </div>
</body>
```

in the CSS

```
#my-div {
  left: -9999px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

EDIT: on reading your question again, I understood differently... you want to keep the div out of view... right?

so you can still use on of the below mentioned jQuery calls to show it... but if you want to keep it hidden the above CSS should be enough... still the object should be rendered and loaded

```
$("#my-div").css({ position: "static" });

// or
$("#my-div").css({ left: 0 });
```